# How to share content not located on device

Tags: android

I need to share files with other apps like Google-Drive did.
Doing this for files located on the device is well documentated.

GDrive seems to provide content-uris and content will be downloaded as needed while another app receives those via a filestream.

Basically I need to create an intent with a list of content-uris which a pure virtual unless the receiving app starts reading those files.
Any advise for this?

Regards

coyer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a provider-section in AbdroidManifest.xml like:

```
<provider
        android:name=".SharedFileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.example.android.SharedFileProvider"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true"
        >
</provider>
```

and create a subclass of "ContentProvider" and implement abstract methods.

The method "openFile" must be overridden to provide the "ParcelFileDescriptor" so the other app could stream from that.